# Ansible error No module named 'pkg_resources'

Tags: python, ansible, freebsd

After executing the following command from the ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Install package required for ansible MySQL modules
  pip: name=mysqlclient executable=/usr/local/bin/pip-3.7*
```

I get the following error:

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_pip_payload_acf1fnah/ansible_pip_payload.zip/ansible/modules/packaging/language/pip.py", line 271, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
fatal: [IP:address]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null,
            "editable": false,
            "executable": "/usr/local/bin/pip-3.7*",
            "extra_args": null,
            "name": [
                "mysqlclient"
            ],
            "requirements": null,
            "state": "present",
            "umask": null,
            "version": null,
            "virtualenv": null,
            "virtualenv_command": "virtualenv",
            "virtualenv_python": null,
            "virtualenv_site_packages": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (setuptools) on freebsd's Python /usr/local/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
}
```

The ansible is running on `Ubuntu` and it is sending commands to `FreeBSD` system.

I have tried to execute this `pip install setuptools`, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that Ansible is using the same Python as `pip`? Compare the output of `head -1 $(which pip)` with `head -1 $(which ansible-playbook)`; do the `#!` lines refer to the same binary?

Comment: On the host machine(ubuntu), one is placing to `#!/usr/bin/python3` and the other is placing to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: how to change it?

Comment: Those two might actually be pointing at the same binary, if `which python3` resolves to `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: So I have changed via vim editor first line of a binary file. And now ansible-playbook and pip are refer to the same binary: `/usr/bin/python3`. But there is still an error. Shoul I restart some services?

Comment: But why this binary matters? Pip is executing on the node server, not on the host, so why I had to chnage these references?

Comment: Hah, my next question was going to be where you were running these tasks (same host as anisble or a remote host), and if you ran your `pip install` command on the remote host, and which Python ansible is using on the remote host (you can inspect the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable), and whether that matches the Python used by the remote `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while using pip module in ansible tasks. I add a step before pip to install python

```html
- name: install python-setuptools by yum
  yum:
    name: python-setuptools
    state: present
    update_cache: yes
```